# What happens if a creature with racial feats is reincarnated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For example if someone were to use reincarnate on a drow who had drow nobility feat what would happen to that feat should the drow become something other than his original race?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character no longer meets the prerequisites for the feat, and therefore can no longer use it:

> Your character must have the indicated [prerequisite] in order to select **or use** that feat.

<sup>([Feats](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html), **emphasis** mine)</sup>

The *reincarnate* spell itself does not provide any mechanism for fixing this problem (other than, arguably, suicide followed by another *reincarnate*, hoping to get a new drow body). It is, however, strongly recommended that some mechanism be allowed to do so—whether that be the optional [retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining/) rules, the third-party [*psychic reformation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/p/psychic-reformation/) power, or just houseruling *reincarnate* to allow replacing feats with racial requirements you no longer meet.