# What happens should a creature with a racial archetype reincarnate?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype

[Related to this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120577/what-happens-if-a-creature-with-racial-feats-is-reincarnated) i want to know what happens should a character who has chosen an archetype related to his race reincarnates to some other creature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Advanced Race Guide](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/featuredRaces.html) :

> Typically, only members of the section's race can take the listed archetype or bloodline, though such options rarely interact with the racial traits or alternate racial traits of that race.

Those are the rules that limit availability, and they don't *strictly* enforce the availability of the archetype. A reincarnated character is not a "typical" case.

Furthermore, [Reincarnate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate/) says the following :

> Its class, base attack bonus, base save bonuses, and hit points are unchanged.

The class is unchanged, which means that the archetype is too (recall that changing an archetype requires retraining). Any level you take in the original class will progress your archetype as well, since it is impossible to progress in the original class and an archetype separately.

Note that while you keep the archetype, some abilities might become unavailable. For example, a [Cavern Sniper](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/featuredRaces/drow.html#cavern-sniper-(fighter)) who is no longer a drow loses access to drow spell-like abilities and can no longer use Imbued Shot.