# Do you lose racial feats when Reincarnated out of your race?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, races, reincarnation

Xanathar’s Guide to Everything introduces racial feats (ex: Bountiful Luck for halflings).

My understanding of the Reincarnate spell is that if you were a variant human and become something else, you lose the variant human’s starting feat. This seems to be supported by Sage Advice : https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/06/18/if-my-pc-is-reincarnated-do-they-lose-their-bonus-feat-and-skills/

Is the same true for racial feats (ex: level 4 halfling with bountiful luck reincarnated into dwarf, loses racial feat?).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### You cannot benefit from the racial feat if your race changes

Page 165 of the PHB says:

> You must meet any prerequisite specified in a feat to take that feat. If you ever lose a feat's prerequisite, you can't use that feat until you regain the prerequisite.

The racial feats in XGtE all have a prerequisite that specifies the race that can take them. For example, Bountiful Luck has the *Halfling* prerequisite.

Therefore, if you are no longer a halfling because of reincarnation, then you cannot use the benefits of the feat.

#### But you will regain the use of the feat if your prerequisite race is restored

As the quote from the PHB says, you can regain the feat's benefits if you regain the prerequisite. So, if something turns you back into whatever race the racial feat requires, you regain the benefit of the feat.

In your example, if you are a halfling, die, and are reincarnated as a dwarf, you would be unable to benefit from the Bountiful Luck feat. But if you then died again and were reincarnated back into a halfling, you would regain the use of Bountiful Luck because you are a halfling again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76095/discussion-on-answer-by-adam-do-you-lose-racial-feats-when-reincarnated-out-of-y).

Comment: As a recommendation for the OP, I would add that in order to the players not feel frustrated by having a worthless feat (meaning they lost almost an entire level worth of features), it is recommended that some ruling or plot is added in order to allow them to change the feat. For reference, the same question was made to pathfinder and answered [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/120581/43856), stating what I've just said.

Comment: @adam would add that in addition to loosing the feats of the old race, that you would gain the feats of the new race.

Comment: @ravery As far as I'm aware, no race aside from variant human gives you a feat as a racial feature, and it's not immediately clear to me that reincarnate would turn you into a variant human over a standard human. While you would certainly have access to the racial feats of the new race, you do not gain any of them unless you choose to take one of them when your class gives you the ability to do so.

Comment: @HellSaint in the case of a feat like "Bountiful Luck", that thematically sounds like something the halfling just 'has', rather then something he trained up, I would probably allow the reincarnated individual to have a similar racial feat for their new race as a consolation.  So, for example, they may be granted the 'dwarven fortitude' feat as long as their a dwarf.  So long as the feet feels like it's something that makes sense for a dwarf to 'just have' because they are a dwarf, instead of a trained skill that dwarves are the only ones to train in.

Comment: I'm going to second what @Hellsaint said above. If you're a dragonborn with the Dragon Hide racial feat, and you get reincarnated as a Halfling, as a DM I would make that reincarnation come with a Halfling racial feat as well in order to balance the feat/ASI progression. The player is already taking a hit by being a different class with a different racial stat loadout, no need to kick them while they're down. Of course.... depending on the campaign and the player, there could be every reason to kick them and then drop the People's Elbow on them while they're down.