# Does the target keep racial ability score bonuses after casting Reincarnate?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits, reincarnation

When casting the spell Reincarnate (PHB pg.271), does the target retain the ability score bonuses of their previous race?

Comment: Related: "[If a Variant Human is Reincarnated, would they lose the feat and skill proficiency they started with?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149503)"

Comment: As of now the question asks if casting reincarnate gets rid of the caster's racial ability score bonuses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### When reincarnated you do not reatain ability score improvements from your previous race

Since your racial ability score improvements come directly from your race's nature, if anything changes your race, whether reincarnation, polymorph, etc. your racial ability score improvements will change just like any other racial trait

Comment: Can you add some references to support this?

Comment: @NeutralVax Your race changes, the mechanics for being your previous race go away. Are you disputing that?

Comment: You can actually add a citation to this. "...except it changes it's original race for the new one and changes it's racial traits accordingly."

Comment: Wildshape changes the race but keeps the original mental stats.